# Transaction with trigger that use a select max. It return wrong result

Tags: mysql, transactions, innodb, mariadb

I have an complex database. I can simplify it like that:

The table a:

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
Id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
A int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
CalcUniqId int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Id)     
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TRIGGER a_before_ins_tr before INSERT on a
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  select Max(CalcUniqId) from A into @MaxCalcUniqId;
  set new.CalcUniqId=IfNull(@MaxCalcUniqId,1)+1;
END $
```

It works like that:

```
start transaction
insert into A(A)
... insert in other tables. It take between 30 and 60 seconds
commit;
```

The problem is, the trigger returns the same CalcUniqId for all transaction that run at the same time.

Is there any solution or work arround.

Is this a solution:

```
start transaction;
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
insert into A(A) values(10);
SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL REPEATABLE READ;
....
commit;
```

Man can run this test:
Session 1:

```
Step1: start transaction;
Step2: insert into A(A) values(1);
Step3: commit;
```

Session 2:

```
Step1: start transaction;
Step2: insert into A(A) values(2);
Step3: commit;
```

Run in session 1 the steps 1,2 and in session 2 the steps 1,2. than step 3 in both. After that do

```
select Id, A, CalcUniqId from a;
```

both have the same CalcUniqId=2.

Comment: Could it be that all the threads are running the `insert` somewhat simultaneously, then getting queued up for the rest of the "inserts"?  Or all of them "simultaneously" finishing after 30-60 seconds?

Comment: hi Rick. I have added some text to my question. thank's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `SELECT` in the Trigger to this:

```
select Max(CalcUniqId) from A into @MaxCalcUniqId
    FOR UPDATE;   -- add this
```

That tells the transaction that you intend to change the value; that blocks the other transactions from changing it.

This will probably lead to your 30-60 sec transactions being run one after another.  And probably dying due to exceeding `lock_wait_timeout`.  Rather than increasing that setting (which is already "too high"), please explain the bigger picture.  Perhaps we can concoct a workaround that gets the 'correct' value *and* runs in parallel.

Comment: hi Rick: wenn i run Step2 there is an error: Can't update table 'a' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.

Comment: My goal is to query the value of CalcUniqId before the commit statment is executed. Regardless of whether rollback or commit is performed. Important is that no two records have the same value.

Comment: And why does `AUTO_INCREMENT` fail to provide such functionality?

Comment: while select Max(CalcUniqId) from A into @MaxCalcUniqId; not only for one table. In  my case it is like that: select max(GlobalCalcUniqId)
from
(
select Max(CalcUniqId) GlobalCalcUniqId from TABLE1
union
select Max(CalcUniqId) from TABLE2
)A
;

Comment: Maybe it cannot be done with a trigger.  Suggest you write out all the statements -- without routines or triggers.  Then rethink the structure of what should _and_ can be moved into routines/triggers.  You may find that a different organization works better.  In particular, the `SELECT MAX...` may have to be an explicit statement just after the `BEGIN`, not hidden in a Trigger.

Comment: I thank you very much Rick. That is really better as y said.